# Issue doing LEFT JOIN twice, (multiplying rows)

Tags: sql, join, left-join

Let's suppose I have 3 tables right now, One table with `lessons`, one table with the `ratings` of those lessons, and one table with the `users` of those lessons.

Lessons is a quite regular table, and the other 2 tables are relation tables like this:

```
TABLE LESSONS
ID | NAME | DESCRIPTION | CREATED BY | APPROVED BY | LEVEL | DATE CREATED | LAST EDIT
1    les1    desc1         10           12            1      12-12-2000     12-12-2000
2    les2    desc2         23           12            2      12-12-2000     12-12-2000
3    les3    desc3         12           12            3      12-12-2000     12-12-2000

TABLE RATINGS
ID | LESSON | USER | RATING | COMMENT
1     1        60      5      very good
2     2        30      4      nice
3     2        62      4      my comment
4     3        65      3      nice
5     3        78      5      very good
6     1        26      1      very bad
6     1        45      3      other comment

TABLE LESSONSXUSERS
ID | LESSON | USER | STATUS
1     1        60     2
2     1        26     2
2     1        45     2
3     2        30     2
4     2        62     2
5     3        65     2
6     3        78     2
7     1        22     1
8     1        19     1
```

And I'm trying to generate a view that shows me only approved lessons, with some info extracted from the other two tables:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `skn_approved_lessons` AS 
select  
 `l`.`id_skn_lessons` AS `id_skn_lessons`,
 `l`.`name` AS `name`,
 `l`.`description` AS `description`,
 `l`.`createdBy` AS `createdBy`,
 `l`.`approvedBy` AS `approvedBy`,
 `l`.`id_skn_lessonsLevels` AS `id_skn_lessonsLevels`,
 `l`.`dateCreated` AS `dateCreated`,
 `l`.`lastEdit` AS `lastEdit`,
 AVG(`lr`.`rating`) AS `avgScore`,
 COUNT(`lxu`.`id_skn_users`) AS `students`
from ((`skn_lessons` AS `l` 
left join `skn_lessonsRatings` AS `lr` on `l`.`id_skn_lessons` = `lr`.`id_skn_lessons`) left join `skn_lessonsXusers` AS `lxu` on `lxu`.`id_skn_lessons` = `l`.`id_skn_lessons`)
where ((`l`.`approvedBy` is not null) and
    (`l`.`approvedBy` <> `l`.`createdBy`))
group by `l`.`id_skn_lessons`;
```

It's "kinda" working, since it shows me what I want, but the amount of users is wrong. I know why this happens, but I don't know how to fix it.

Issue is, I should get this:

```
VIEW APPROVED
ID | NAME | DESCRIPTION | CREATED BY | APPROVED BY | LEVEL | DATE CREATED | LAST EDIT  | AVG RATING | STUDENTS
1    les1    desc1         10           12            1      12-12-2000     12-12-2000       3          4
2    les2    desc2         23           12            2      12-12-2000     12-12-2000       4          2
3    les3    desc3         12           12            3      12-12-2000     12-12-2000       4          2
```

But I'm getting this:

```
VIEW APPROVED
ID | NAME | DESCRIPTION | CREATED BY | APPROVED BY | LEVEL | DATE CREATED | LAST EDIT  | AVG RATING | STUDENTS
1    les1    desc1         10           12            1      12-12-2000     12-12-2000       3          15
2    les2    desc2         23           12            2      12-12-2000     12-12-2000       4          4
3    les3    desc3         12           12            3      12-12-2000     12-12-2000       4          4
```

Notice users column is wrong, what I'm really getting is the product of `users`x`amountOfRatings`. It's making the query with each registry of `user` by each registry of `rating`, so I'll always get the `users`x`ratings` as the amount of `users`, which is NOT what I want.

I don't quite understand how to do the second join after grouping by `lesson.id`, that I guess will solve the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you make a sqlfiddle? I tried making one from the data you posted, but the column names are different from the column in the query.

Comment: Is it a typo that there are 2 ratings with id=6 and 2 LESSONSXUSERS with id=2? Anyhow, it is probably a good idea to create a sqlfiddle.

Comment: I think you may just need to use `COUNT(DISTINCT lxu.id_skn_users)`, but I wanted to test it before I posted an answer.

Comment: Distinct is exactly what I was missing, it seems to work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe all you need to do is to add the DISTINCT argument to the COUNT aggregate function as follows:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT lxu.id_skn_users)
```

Adding the DISTINCT argument will return the number of unique nonnull values from that column.

I see Barmar already put that into the comments above.